# How to convert apiDoc to postman collection?

Tags: postman, api-doc, postman-collection

I have a nodejs project with many requests implemented and well documented by apiDoc, and I want to create a Postman collection from it!

```
> example:

/**
     * @api {GET} config/updates Updates - Get the latest event updates
     * @apiGroup Config service
     * @apiDescription This api endpoint provides the latest updates that need to be fetched by the client. It provides
         * an array of events, based on either the latestupdate (timestamp) param, or a configured interval (currently default to 1 minute.
...
..
    */
```

It is possible to create from apiDoc a postman collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export your apiDoc to Swagger and then import it to Postman.

**1.Export to Swagger**

- Install this [npm-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apidoc-swagger)
- npm install apidoc-swagger -g
- apidoc-swagger -i example/ -o doc/ (example is the input and doc is the output)

**2.Import in Postman**

Postman supports swagger files so you can import it without issues you can read about it [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/data_formats) read 'Importing swagger' section.

The npm package may not work because it seems outdated.

Comment: thanks :D ! 
I checked this npm module, I found some bugs on the code but but eventually I fixed  them and the result ( *.json) is good.

Comment: @KrauszLórántSzilveszter Nice, you are welcome and thanks :D can you please share your edits ?

Comment: That library is not maintained anymore. Try at your own risk.